# Can Somebody Helps me out in fixing -collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int size, i ,j, values[3][3];
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    printf("Please enter the array limit\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("The entered values of array");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(j=0; j<size; j++){
        scanf("%d",&values[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("The entered values in matrix\n");
        for(i=0; i<size; i++){
            for(j=0; j<size; j++){
            printf("%d",values[i][j]);
            }
        }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**The console **

```
20:42:57 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Func multi Dim  Practice ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -o "Func multi Dim  Practice.exe" "src\\Func multi Dim  Practice.o" 
C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Func multi Dim  Practice.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to Solve it myself by Surfing but failed and I am not able to move forward.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you only look at the summary, you will not see the error messages. Start reading from the top. The error to seach for is "ld.exe: cannot open output file xy.exe: Permission denie" You should find lots of questions about that very same message. Yet the reasons for that error might differ.

Comment: Not causing your problem, but generally blanks in file names are a bad idea. You will always have to escape them or put the name into quotes. Whenever you forget that, things will start going wrong.

Comment: Thanx for your Quick response , but , could you  help me in fixing these.....  Much obliged

Comment: No, i don't use that setup and don't know the solution. As I mentioned, there may be multiple reasons. When you searched SO for that message, didn't the answers help you? Also I do not see any point in repeating what has been answered in tons of questions already. This error message is asked about at least every other day. No need to create more duplicates.